# Shared SSH connection with Control Master not working

Tags: sockets, ssh, openssh, ssh-multiplexing

I have set up sharing an ssh connection on my local machine fine, but when I try and do this on our CI server it is failing and I cant work out why.

the ~/.ssh/config is

```
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
ControlPersist 2h
```

First connection will fail, but will create the socket, second connection will fail as the socket is stale.

The end of the verbose output from first connection is....

```
$ ssh -vvvv -N  user@domain.co.uk

....

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000

....

Authenticated to domain.co.uk ([88.47.112.93]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /home/rof/.ssh/control:domain.co.uk:22:user.3HfyjbhRCDHGwnrI
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [/home/rof/.ssh/control:domain.co.uk:22:user]
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 4
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process
debug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 84004
Control socket connect(/home/rof/.ssh/control:domain.co.uk:22:user): Connection refused
Failed to connect to new control master
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 7200 seconds
```

If you run it without the -N option the command input just hangs.

any subsequent ssh connections say the socket is stale and unlink it, thus not using a shared connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue, this was due to the fact the the CI server we use uses `overlayfs` as its filesystem, which doesn't play nice with unix sockets.

To fix this, I saved the socket in virtual memory instead..

```
ControlPath /var/shm/control:%h:%p:%r
```

Comment: You're a life saver - thanks! On my setup I had to change `/var/shm` to the more common `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Experienced the same issue while trying to set up control masters within an Ubuntu LiveCD prompt -- same solution works there too!